# Databricks Autoloader multiple folders

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

I have a hard time to understand how autoloader will work with multiple folders in adls gen 2 and how should I pass the  `data_source` path.

I have the following folder strcutre, where data is loading for multiple tables in evey 15 min in my storage account. Root directory looks like this:

[image]
In each folder I have the actual data per table

[image]

```
    data_source = f"abfss://name@prodstorage.dfs.core.windows.net/{what should be a as root directory parameter}/{table_name}/*.csv"
source_format = "csv"



# Configure Auto Loader to ingest csv data to a Delta table
df = (
    spark.readStream
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("quote", '"')
    .option("mode", "permissive")
    .option("lineSep", "\r\n")
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", source_format)
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_directory)
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("escape", '"')
    .schema(schema)
    .load(data_source)
```

question is how should I pass the data source path to code that will work with autoloader?

Comment: In which of this folder your csv files present `msdyn_workorder`,`nrq_customerasset...`,`optionmetadata`?

Comment: in all of them, I have 3 delta table called same names as you listed. and i would like to load data in there reading from each folder accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Autoloader can process one file at a time, it stores last processed file, it can do the structure streaming.

Autoloader provides a structured streaming source called cloud files to incrementally and efficiently process new data. As they arrive in cloud storage.

```
.option("recursiveFileLookup",'True')
```

The above code will let you ignore folder level partitioning into incoming data frame.

Recursive file lookup is used if you have any kind of partitioning into data frame in that case you can turn it ON or OFF to make use of it.

Automation of data loading process by using cloud native components to filter out the newly arrived files.

***Note: A cloud files datareader is a component that read data from a cloud based file system, such as Amazon s3, ADLS gen 2
Cloud Notification Services:Cloud notification services are services provided by cloud based files system that allow you to receive notification when changes occur in the file system (or) the deletion of existing file.***

To pass the data source path to code that will work with Autoloader

```
df=(
spark.readStream.format('cloudFiles')
.option('cloudFiles.format',"CSV")
.option('cloudFiles.schemaLocation',Schema_loc)
.option('header',True)
.load(Source_data_loc)
)
```

For example, I have to folder **SampleFiles**and it consist of 2 Emp table and Dept Table.

[image]

[image]
[image]
The Output is written to **target_data_loc**
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for this explanation but, mainly i was wondering if autolaoder could work on my folder structure. You solution has different folder structure. in My case newly arrived files are in different folder

Comment: @Greencolor Automation of data loading process by using cloud native components to filter out the newly arrived files. samplefile  folder is within the Folder1 container.
try giving the qualified path and retry the load once again. Know more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/directory-listing-mode#incremental-listing